# Table loading data with each scroll

Tags: html, javascript, scrolling, selenium

does someone know a website that has a big table (a few columns and many rows) that loads each time we do scroll down?

I'd like to extract some data of a big table with selenium or JavaScript with "waitToVisible" but I cannot share the actual website since is confidential, so, I want to try with a public website if possible.

I've been searching a site with that characteristics. In Wikipedia there are several tables but don't show "loading..." the new content if I do scroll.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: youtube has infinite scroll

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'd like to test with some site similar to the actual site that basically is a table of 7 columns that shows only about 50 rows and after I scroll down appears "loading" and shows the next 50 and has thousands of rows. So is not  possible to do a "select all" to copy table content. The actual table has one column that always shows the same string and I using a "waitToBe Visible" event for xpath of that element nut doesn't work.

Comment: If you google something like: "codepen infinite scroll table" and add some lines of JS you probably have what you want

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion